# toFixed Condition for decimal values

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I have a reponsed from API in decimal format like this 89.9999 and I have used toFixed and rounded off to 89.90 .But the problem is if I get value as 90, becuase of toFixed it displays as 90.00 ,where as I need only 90. Is there any way to implement this ?

Code I tried for basic calculation is :

```
 var myPerc= value.studPerc === 0 ? '0' : value.studPerc.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Use `Math.round`. `toFixed` does what you experience. It is simply a different usecase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this to checking using `%`

> Whenever we use `Integer%1` it will return `0` of if we use `Float%1` it will return some point value like `0.####`.

**DEMO**

```js
function setToFixed(v) {
  console.log(v % 1 ? v.toFixed(2) : v)
}

setToFixed(90)


setToFixed(89.7589999)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use modulus `%` to detect first if value is a decimal, so you can do it like below

```
var value = n % 1 !== 0 ? n.toFixed(2) : n;
```

Comment: Great.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice` after `toFixed` to remove the trailing `.00` if they exist:

```js
const getPerc = num => {
  const str = num.toFixed(2);
  if (str.slice(-2) === '00') return str.slice(0, str.length - 3);
  return str;
}
console.log(getPerc(90));
console.log(getPerc(89.9999));
console.log(getPerc(89.55));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Math.round(value * 100) / 100
```